# Change script to work only on specific tab

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this script:

```
function onEdit2(e) {
  const sheetName = "Charts"; // Please set your sheet name.
  const dropDownCell = "B4:B6"; // Please set the range of dropdown list.
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var cell = spreadsheet.getActiveCell();
  var cellR = cell.getRow();
  var cellC = cell.getColumn();
  var cellValue = cell.getValue();
  if (cellR == 4 && cellC == 2) {
    spreadsheet.getRange('B6').clearContent();
    spreadsheet.getRange('B6').setValue('⚠️ SELECT');
  }
}
```

I would like to make it work **only** on **Charts** tab without affecting any other tab. Right now script works in all tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the code doesn't make much sense to me.  Here's what it boils down to:

```
function onEdit2(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Charts" && e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.range.rowStart == 4) {
    sh.getRange('B6').setValue('⚠️ SELECT');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit2(e) {
  const sheetName = "Charts"; // Please set your sheet name.
  if( e.range.getSheet().getName() === sheetName ) {
    const dropDownCell = "B4:B6"; // Please set the range of dropdown list.
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var cell = spreadsheet.getActiveCell();
    var cellR = cell.getRow();
    var cellC = cell.getColumn();
    var cellValue = cell.getValue();
    if (cellR == 4 && cellC == 2) {
      spreadsheet.getRange('B6').clearContent();
      spreadsheet.getRange('B6').setValue('⚠️ SELECT');
    }
  }
}
```